# Android - UnSupportedOperation Exception at GCMRegistrar.checkDevice()

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-5.0-lollipop, unsupportedoperation

I am developing an android application in which I would like to implement the GCM feature. I could able to implement and it is working fine in Android Kitkat 4.4 version (Tested on Micromax 089). But not working in the devices(such as **Lava Iris Fuel F1** and **Moto x play**) which runs on Android Lolipop(Android 5.0) and above.

The code snippet which I used for verifying the device dependencies and Manifest permissions

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
```

and the app crashed at `GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);`

**Screenshot of Logcat**.

[image: Screenshot of Logcat]

With some research , I found some of the reasons that I listed below,by which the app may be crashed

1. The app may not be targeted to Google API.
2. The Google Play services may not be installed.
3. Internet may not be available.
4. Connection to the own server could be down.

Even I have verified all the above scenarios, could not fix the issue.

Please help me finding the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Have you added this code in your manifest?

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

By the way GCMRegistrar is obselete and i wouldnt recommend it. Use this
[GCM Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start)

You can try using the [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) library instead of the deprecated library that contains GCMRegistrar. This is because some devices don't have this package **com.google.android.gsf** in their skin of Android particularly Lenovo and Motorola which is why you must be getting the Unsupported Exception on checkDevice()

Comment: The manifest file have this snippet . But does not work in Android 5.0 and above versions..@Hackose

Comment: @RakeshL you should switch to the new Google Cloud Messaging

Comment: @Hackose  Thanks Hackose . One more clarification is needed. Before the API you preferred, is introduced how it was tackled to support all devices. including those devices I mentioned in my question ?